# Will PC printers work on my Mac if I used Parallels?

Tags: mac, osx-snow-leopard, drivers

I have a Macbook Pro Snow Leopard. I want to buy a Dell Laser printer (currently looking at Dell 1320c). As far as I know, it does not have an official driver for Snow Leopard.

If I bought Parallels, and ran, say, Windows 7 and install the printer drivers, will it work?

I dont mind having to launch Windows every time I need to print something.m

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yup, it works. Installed the drivers just like a regular drivers.

Comment: You should mark the question as answered if you found the solution.

Answer (score 2):

As long as the device is visible from the VM then you should be able to print from it.  Most of the time this will be the case.  Does the printer have a driver for any OS X?  Even if it's not for snow leopard but an older OS X it should be fine.

Even if that all fails you should be able to use a generic driver.